# How to ping an ipaddress at a specific port ios app

Tags: ios

Im trying to ping all ip addresses at my network. I'm able to get my ip now im trying to ping all of other ip's in my network. i have this ip xxx.xxx.xxx.121 , il have to ping xxx.xxx.xxx.1 to xxx.xxx.xxx.255.Im using simpleping by the way.

```
for (int i = 0; i<256; i++) {
        NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%i",searchingIp,i];
        NSLog(@"ipStr:%@",str);

        const char *address = [str UTF8String];
        NSLog(@"%s",address);

        struct sockaddr_in callAddress;
        callAddress.sin_len = sizeof(callAddress);
        callAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
        callAddress.sin_port = htons(49160);
        callAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(address);

        NSLog(@"%s:%d",inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in*)&callAddress)->sin_addr),((struct sockaddr_in*)&callAddress)->sin_port);


        simplePing = [SimplePing simplePingWithHostAddress:[NSData dataWithBytes:&callAddress length:sizeof(callAddress)]];
        simplePing.delegate = self;
        [simplePing start];
    }
```

I also tried to set the port with "49160" but still it shows 2240.
Im kinda new in this type of stuff.

Comment: Try using `ntohs()` to convert the port number back to host format in your `NSLog` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you are using the SimplePing example written by Apple (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SimplePing/Introduction/Intro.html)

Then, I think there is a methond that allows you to initalize it using the hostname:

```
+ (SimplePing *)simplePingWithHostName:(NSString *)hostName
```

And then it should be easier to write something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i<256; i++) {
        NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%i",searchingIp,i];
        NSLog(@"ipStr:%@",str);

        simplePing = [SimplePing simplePingWithHostName:str];
        simplePing.delegate = self;
        [simplePing start];
    }
```

BTW, ICMP is not TCP/UDP so I do not think is has port abstraction but message types like echo.